# How do I set a cookie on localhost with Phalcon?

Tags: cookies, phalcon

In normal PHP, to set a cookie you need to run the following code:

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = FALSE [, bool $httponly = FALSE ]]]]]] )
```

And to get it to work on localhost, string `$domain` needs to be `false`.

To set a cookie with Phalcon, you need to run the following code:

```
public set (mixed $name, [mixed $value], [mixed $expire], [mixed $path], [mixed $secure], [mixed $domain], [mixed $httpOnly])
```

However, when I try and send the `[mixed $domain]` as `false` I get the following error:

> Parameter 'domain' must be a string

Setting it to `''`, `null`, `'localhost'`, `'.localhost'`, or `'127.0.0.1'` doesn't throw an error, but doesn't save the cookie.

The next thing my code does is `$this->response->redirect()`.

How can I get cookies to work on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$this->cookies->set("<cookie-name>", "<cookie-value>", time);
```

The domain is optional.